# Display callback methods

Tags: windows-phone-7

In Android and iOS there are callback methods to let you know if a screen has been loaded such onCreate, onResume.. etc. I was wondering if there is something similar on WP7. I am using a pivotview and i would like to be notified when the user scrolls to a specific screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by "scrolls" you mean swipes to a new pivot item?

`Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Pivot` is an `ItemsControl`, you can subscribe to the `SelectionChanged` event to see when the user switches pivots.

If you mean "navigates" like loading a new page, that's a different thing.